# PHP Form submit to Get All Option Values?

Tags: php, html

Here i just want to discus about the following:

My HTML From like the fllowing code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="sample" method="post" action="saveData.php">
Courses:
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" Value="C++" />C++
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" Value="PHP"/>PHP
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" Value="MYSQL" />MYSQL
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" Value=".Net"/>.Net
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gen[]" Value="male"/>male
<input type="radio" name="gen[]" Value="female"/>Female
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I Want the OutPut Like The Following:

```
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        $actVal .= "'".strtolower($key)."|".strtolower($val)."',";
        $sqlin .= " ".strtolower($key)." VARCHAR(255) , ";
                }
```

But I got The Output like which one clicked in that options:

Like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------
male
C++
```

but I need it like the following:

```
male,female
C++,PHP,MYSQL,.Net
```

Comment: @billyonecan can give some sample code for that....

Comment: You can never get the first output(`male C++`) from that code. There is no value attribute in the `<input type="checkbox"` element. Repost your code.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add in this question @SandyLee_user53167 now i have added...

Comment: whatever you're doing. you're not doing it in the best way possible. if you explain the case and what you're actually trying to do, we can help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST will send all values if you mark them as selected using javascript right before submitting. $_POST["check"] is an array. use a foreach and get all values from that array.

Comment: Great idea, but how do we distinguish between user-selected checkbox an those selected by js?

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167 is that even what OP is trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not sure but what is the need to make the form in the first place if we want all the values?

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167 op is probably doing an elementary school homework in this case

Comment: I hope he/she gets an `A`.

Comment: @SandyLee_user53167 I hope his teacher gives him a more logical case to analyse and develop

Answer (score 1):

As you're loop through post data which is going to be an array I believe that is why only one of their elements are being returned.

You might want to try something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if ($key == "check" || $key == "gen") { // If this is an array post field
        foreach ($val as $val2) { // We need to loop through again since they're array post fields
            $actVal .= "'" . strtolower($val2) . "'";
        }   
    } else {
        $actVal .= "'".strtolower($key)."|".strtolower($val)."',";
    }
    //$sqlin .= " ".strtolower($key)." VARCHAR(255) , "; // Worry about this separately, should be the same process
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out a way around that one. But there is an alternative:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="php" />PHP
<input type="hidden" name="checklist" value="php" />

<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="MySQL" />MySQL
<input type="hidden" name="checklist" value="MySQL" />
```

The idea is to store the list of all the values of a checkbox/radio button, in a hidden input so that you get the list of those values server-side, when the form is submitted.

BTW, why do you need it  anyway?

Comment: this is fine if i am having a textbox or something but if i want to implement this in radio or checkbox means it wont,work.............